# Smarty concatenate string and variable as parameter for a modifier

Tags: php, concatenation, smarty3

How can I concatenate multiple strings and variables inside a parameter of a modifier in Smarty 3?

```
{$message|modifier:'something':'bla'$foo'bla':'hello'} //gives the error: Unexpected "$", expected one of: "}"

{$message|modifier:'something':'bla'.$foo.'bla':'hello'} //gives the error: Unexpected ".", expected one of: "}"

{$message|modifier:'something':'bla'`$foo`'bla':'hello'} //gives the error: Unexpected "`", expected one of: "}"

{$message|modifier:'something':'bla'{$foo}'bla':'hello'} //gives the error: Unexpected "{", expected one of: "}"

{$message|modifier:'something':'bla{$foo}bla':'hello'} //the parameter evaluates to "bla{$foo}bla"
```

Using the `cat` modifier doesn't work either since you can't use it inside a parameter of another modifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it using  `cat`:

```
{$message|modifier:'something':{'bla'|cat:$foo|cat:'bla'}:'hello'}
```